# Using a Java client that uses HTTPClient

Tags: java, apache

I have written a Java client that has the HTTPClient and JSON jar's included. When I created a runnable jar of my client (to give out to others), I selected "Extract Required libraries into generated JAR". Is this legal under Apache 2.0 (which is HTTP)? When I selected "Package required libraries into generated JAR" and attempted to use my client to make rest calls from another application I get the error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.ContentBody
```

I do not get an error when I use Extract. Am I doing it the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

Does your runnable jar include the contents of the apache jars that your code depends on? If not, it won't run, with the exact behavior you describe.

The apache library does allow this BTW.